# Rack 2.0.1 requires Ruby >= 2.2.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rack

I am trying to run "bundle update", but I keep getting the error message:

```
An error occurred while installing rack (2.0.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install rack -v '2.0.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Then I install rack 2.0.1:

```
sudo gem install rack -v 2.0.1
Successfully installed rack-2.0.1
Parsing documentation for rack-2.0.1
Done installing documentation for rack after 2 seconds
1 gem installed
```

Then I even ran "rbenv rehash", and I run "bundle update" again and the same error message shows up. How do I get Bundler to recognize the new gem?

Comment: Are you sure your `sudo` Ruby is the same one you're trying to install `bundler` with? Sometimes your root user is using a different Ruby altogether. With `rbenv` you shouldn't need to `sudo` install, and if you do, maybe you're doing something wrong.

Comment: @tadman when I try and install rack without sudo, I get 'Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /Users/SamLerner/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/COPYING'

Comment: You've mangled your permissions with a previous `sudo` install. You can normally fix that with `chown -R` on that directory.

Comment: On the directory in the error message?

Comment: Try running `chown -R /Users/SamLerner/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems`, should fix it.

Comment: I did that and was able to gem install rack without sudo, but when I try running bundle update, it still says I don't have it installed

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have the "bundler" installed from the ruby version installed by rbenv first. Then, check the ruby version in that directory. It should be the one that you installed from rbenv or rvm. After these, if you are installing something just don't use `sudo` before `bundle`. Because `bundle` is from the rbenv ruby version. If the `rbenv rehash` doesn't work, just restart the bash and check.

If the without `sudo` thing needs permission, you are most likely using the bundler that was installed by your system ruby as `sudo gem install bundler`.

Try reinstalling bundler without a sudo like `gem install bundler` and retry.

Even if that doesn't work, remove the Gemfile.lock in your directory. Remove any version of rack mentioned in your Gemfile if any. Just have the gem name like `gem 'rack'` and try `bundle install` again. The gem that you could install with `sudo` was stored for the system ruby, not the one you have installed through `rbenv`.

Comment: On my machine, I didn't realize that I was using the bundler from the non-rbenv (i.e. system default ruby). Once you've changed an environment using ebenv, be sure to run `gem install bundler`.

Answer (score 0):

When you ran `sudo install`, your gem most probably got installed under a different directory. When using Rbenv or VRM, you shouldn't use `sudo`.

First of all you could try uninstalling the gem from your system gems and doing it again without sudo.

Going into extremes you could completely reinstall your rbenv with gems (and while at it switch to RVM, personally I think its easier to manage). After that try to bundle install everything again without sudo and it should work.